# 2 page SSRS report, over flow data on additional page not getting header or footer

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on a 2 page SSRS report where sometimes data on the first page will run over to a 2nd page, (making it a 3 page report) however, the customer info that shows up in the header is not showing up on the 2nd page( in the over flow). it works when you run for one customer but if you run a whole region with multiple customers and one customer has tons of orders where a continuation of the first page is needed, the customer demo info does not display in the header

Comment: Providing screen shots would be most helpful.   Hard to see exactly what you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

I tried with some dummy data to reproduce the scenario but not getting such issue.
Check out the attached screenshot. 
Please provide some more details with snapshot to figure it out.
[Report Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbjXR.jpg)[Report snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL0I9.jpg)